# How to make it more difficult to 'tweak' your OS?

Tags: linux, command-line, software-installation

One of the strengths of Linux is also its weakness. The ease and simplicity to install apps and modify your OS.

Also AFAIK  Linux has no  **restore point**  capability like Windows so often figuring out what is causing crashes, and other issues becomes problematic.
It's too tempting to be constantly adding tweaks.

Are there any ways to make it much more difficult to do a  `sudo apt-get` or `sudo yum install`?

Comment: I'd say simply limiting root privileges to certain people is enough, as the people that have root should be able to use it wisely. You can also create a restore point-esque system using dd.

Comment: If you're not able to deny root access to users who like to meddle, perhaps you should investigate snapshottable filesystems (Btrfs is probably the most mainstream), and generate snapshots at suitable intervals (for the filesystems containing `/usr/` and `/etc/` at least).

Comment: Thanks. Would SystemBack or Timeshift be as useful as  Btrfs or dd for creating system snapshots?

Comment: `yum history` gives you pretty simple rollback option.  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec2-Yum-Transaction_History-Reverting.html

Comment: Make sure to install etckeeper, which maintains a history of `/etc`.

Comment: Why is the answer not the obvious “don't use `sudo`”?